# How large a checksum file can md5sum handle?

Tags: 12.04, md5sum

I have a large collection of files (87.3 GB and 80054 objects) which I am copying from drive to drive. To make sure everything went well, I have made a checksum file to check with `md5sum -c checksums.txt`. Every time I try this, suddenly lightdm crashes (at least that's what I think is happening), and I am presented with the login screen. My session is gone.

What might cause this?

Does `md5sum` has a limit to how large checksum files or number of files it can handle? (Limited by system specs?)

---

**Info:**
`checksums.txt` is 7.6 MB and has 79281 lines.
The destination drive is an external NTFS formatted one.
I run Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Update: I managed to successfully check all files by dividing the original checksum file into a few smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

`md5sum` doesn't has limitation of  checksum files or number of files, but maybe the problem is that `md5sum` can not handle subfolders. 
Try to install `md5deep`, which allow to make checksum for subfolders recursively and works smoothly with large number of files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem, as it works when I split up the original checksum  file.